# PHP array_push on database rows doesn't work for all of them (using a WHILE loop)

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I'm looking to add a *_*_ in the Array variable for each of the rows in the database.
In my testTable I currently have 2 rows though when running this code only one is 'pushed' to the array.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testTable ORDER BY dateAdded DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $Array = array();
    array_push($Array, array('id' => $row['id'], 'title' => $row['title'], 'desc' => $row['desc'],  'image' => $row['image'], 'dateAdded' => $row['dateAdded']);
}

print_r($Array);
```

The output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => test test test [desc] => text text text [image] => http://domain.com/sampleImg.png [dateAdded] => 2012-06-13 15:58:43 ) )
```

It worked when I tried to just echo the title for example... like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$Array` should be `$productsArray` and should be outside your loop

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testTable ORDER BY dateAdded DESC");
$productsArray= array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($productsArray, array('id' => $row['id'], 'title' => $row['title'], 'desc' => $row['desc'],  'image' => $row['image'], 'dateAdded' => $row['dateAdded']);
}

print_r($productsArray);
```

Comment: This would reset the `$productsArray` for every iteration of the `while` loop.  I doubt this is the desired behavior.

Comment: Make sure it is outside of your loop

Comment: Uhh yeah $Array was changd from $productsArray actually.. still editing.

Answer (score 2):

While @JohnConde's answer will work, it would be better if you structured your code like this instead:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, `desc`, image, dateAdded FROM testTable ORDER BY dateAdded DESC");
$productsArray = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $productsArray[] = $row;
}

print_r($productsArray);
```

It's wasteful to `SELECT *` if you're only going to use a certain subset of fields.  It's also wasteful to reconstruct an array to be added to `$productsArray`, which is essentially equal to the array returned by `mysql_fetch_array()`.

**Edit:**  It's also worth noting that the `mysql` driver is no longer recommended for use in new applications.  I would advise that you use either [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), or the [MySQL Native Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) instead.

Comment: If you're suggesting code restructuring, then don't ommit the obligatory failure test on the mysql results: `... or die(mysql_error())`. assuming a query has succeeded is a major source of problems/bugs.

Comment: @MarcB: That would be adding code, not restructuring.  I leave it as an exercise to the OP to add in his own error-handling. :-)

Comment: Or better yet, suggest throwing off the ancient `mysql` library (it's even worse than IE6 now). )) Seriously, +1 for easy optimizing technique. )

Comment: @raina77ow:  I agree, and I haven't used `mysql` in years.  I added the recommended alternatives to my answer.